# How to vectorize the information extraction from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

The code below extracts information from the DataFrame df and fills up another DataFrame df_cust cell-by-cell. This code does what I want but it is taking time. The df contains 20000 rows. How can I vectorize this piece of code?

```
    for i,col in enumerate(df.columns):
      for prod in df[df[col].notna()][col]:
        df_cust.at[i,prod] = 1
```

Comment: I don't understand what this code is doing. Maybe better show code with example data and expected result. But some problems can't be vectorized.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.